# Programmatically grant a user the ability to log on using remote desktop

Tags: windows, rdp

I have several Windows Server 2022 hosts that I need to manage the user rights assignment through automation.

When I manually grant a domain user **SeRemoteInteractiveLogonRight** rights, they cannot log on using remote desktop, they receive an error stating they are not authorized. If I grant them membership in the local **Remote Desktop Users** group, they can log on successfully.

The **Remote Desktop Users** group is granted the **SeRemoteInteractiveLogonRight** right, but no other rights.

What other permission has that group been granted that I would also need to grant to individual users to enable the ability?

Comment: Logging on via RDP requires user rights AND permissions. See the linked article on how to grant the permissions using WMI... BUT... wouldn't it be easier to programatically add the users to the Remote Desktop Users group? - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/remote/add-user-services-rdp-permissions#:~:text=Open%20Terminal%20Services%20Configuration.,the%20wanted%20users%20and%20groups.

Comment: Neither the GUI nor the wmi class exist in these hosts, I believe that document references Windows terminal services (the multi-user mode), not remote desktop.

Comment: Terminal Services and Remote Desktop Services are the same thing. Microsoft renamed Terminal Services to Remote Desktop Services. My point being, assigning the user rights alone isn't sufficient. The user(s) must also have the appropriate permissions. Adding the users to the local Remote Desktop Users group accomplishes both.

Comment: I was able to add an account (and the user right) and log in. However, I agree and you are right that using the group greatly simplifies the correct configuration and I have updated the approach to use that facility. I have opened a support case merely for the academic aspect of knowing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SeRemoteInteractiveLogonRight** is a Privilege (you can grant this privilege with the following policy: [Allow log on through Remote Desktop Services](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/allow-log-on-through-remote-desktop-services)). As the documentation says:

> This policy setting determines which users or groups can access the
> logon screen of a remote device through a Remote Desktop Services
> connection[...]

Great! However, as you saw it, the users still receives an error message unless they are members of Remote Desktop Users. That's documented too:

> To use Remote Desktop Services to successfully log on to a remote
> device, the user or group must be a member of the Remote Desktop Users
> or Administrators group and be granted the Allow log on through Remote
> Desktop Services right.[...]

Well, this is because there are (at least) two layers:

1. The *Remote Desktop Service security descriptor*: Remote Desktop service has **its own** access list.
2. The *SeRemoteInteractiveLogonRight* privilege

The order is relevant here: The user connects to Remote Desktop Services first, and if this is allowed, then Windows will check that the user's token holds the SeRemoteInteractiveLogonRight before opening the user's session.

You can see the *Remote Desktop Service security descriptor* in the [Win32_TSPermissionsSetting WMI class](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/termserv/win32-tspermissionssetting) (`StringSecurityDescriptor` for RDP-Tcp). For example, you can give the StringSecurityDescriptor to the Powershell cmdlet `ConvertFrom-SddlString` to see its content in a prettier format :

```
$sddl = Get-WmiObject -class win32_tspermissionssetting -Namespace root\cimv2\terminalservices | where {$_.TerminalName -eq "RDP-Tcp"} |select StringSecurityDescriptor

ConvertFrom-SddlString -Sddl $sddl.StringSecurityDescriptor | select -ExpandProperty DiscretionaryAcl
```

The output will show you that the Remote Desktop Users group is allowed by default:

```
[...]
Remote Desktop Users: AccessAllowed
[...]
```

Basically, granting `SeRemoteInteractiveLogonRight` will not add the user/group to the Remote Desktop security descriptor, so, Remote Desktop Services denies the logon **before** Windows even had to check if the SeRemoteInteractiveLogonRight was granted.

You can manually add users or groups in the Remote Desktop Services security descriptor with the [AddAccount](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/termserv/win32-tspermissionssetting-addaccount) method: the SDDL will be modified and you'll see your account/group in it. If you granted the `SeRemoteInteractiveLogonRight` privilege, then you should be able to log on (unless other restrictions are effective on this computer or user, of course).

Now, what happens if you add a user in the Remote Desktop Service security descriptor, without granting `SeRemoteInteractiveLogonRight`? Well, Remote Desktop Services will accept the connection, but you'll see an error when Windows tries to open your session, and as you can see, this is not an error thrown by the RDP client, the graphics channel is opened and the error is shown by the remote computer:

[image: Unable to logon because the privilege is missing, error message shown]

And that's what the security auditing logs tells us in this case (if you are auditing):

[image: Event ID 4625 failed RDP logon]

You'll **not** see this event if the user is not allowed to connect according to the Remote Desktop Service security descriptor because the logon operation fails before Windows had a chance to check privileges.

I strongly recommend you to use the `Remote Desktop Users` group, because this group is present by default in the Remote Desktop service security descriptor, and is allowed to use the `SeRemoteInteractiveLogonRight` privilege (unless the server is a DC). You should not need to fiddle with the RDS security descriptor.